# Run windows command in php

Tags: php, exec, system

Is it possible to run windows command line code from php ?
My windows command line code is:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
try {

echo exec('C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysqlbinlog --start-datetime="2011-04-21 10:31:44" c:\xampp\mysql\data\binlog\bin-log.000001 > c:\xampp\mysql\data\binlog\sql.txt');

} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Now I want to run this code from PHP using `system()` or `exec()` etc.
any help appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: What is the problem? You can use it anyone from both.

Comment: I think you can user `shell_exec` function to achieve this... if system() and exec() not working

Answer (score 18):

If you are able to run your commands manually from the command-line, but not via WAMP, than the user the Apache Service runs as does not have the needed permissions to execute your commands and binaries (nor interact with the desktop if it is GUI related).

By default, Apache service run under user account: **nt authority\system**

Change it to your custom user (user with administrative rights) by following below steps,

1. Hit Windows+R which opens Run
2. Type "services.msc" which opens list of windows services
3. Find and select your apache service and open its properties
4. Go to Logon tab and change the account From “Local System” to another user/account
5. Restart your Apache service

Happy coding :-)

Comment: I had to use Administrator

Comment: @Black You can use administrator credentials

Comment: After using administrator I was unable to start the service

Comment: Try using the command line PHP process as administrator. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67910311/6862516

Answer (score 7):

I'm using wamp, and the only solution was the followings:

At Control Panel / Administrative tools / Services, search for wampapache64, httpd, or something like that. On the Log On tab tick the 'allow service to interact with desktop'

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did not find anything similar in the control panel.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't run the command directly in exec(), then what you can do is make a batch file with the command and place it on the root of your website. Then, just run:

```
<?php echo exec("script.bat"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give it a try. Or if you want a sandbox example just try to run

```
<?php echo exec("whoami");?>
```

Comment: i use this exec('C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysqlbinlog --start-datetime="2011-04-21 10:31:44" c:\xampp\mysql\data\binlog\bin-log.000001 > sql.txt');

Comment: You could either check your php.ini to see whether exec() is allowed. Or put error_reporting(E_ALL); at the beginning of your script to see what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

`C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysqlbinlog` is not a command.

I think you mean `C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqlbinlog`.

Notice the replacing of the `>` in a `\`.

The `>` is only visible in the command prompt as a separator (for the eyes) but you should not use it like that in a command unless you are trying to redirect your output. (which you are doing again later in the line). So just replace that first `>` in a `\` and your command will run.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? You should not get any echo back from exec in this case. You're redirecting output to sql.txt. After replacing the > in \ before `mysqlbinlog` it worked here as expected. (a sql.txt is created) If you want the output in the browser you should remove the `> c:\xampp\mysql\data\binlog\sql.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Run **Command Prompt as administrator**.

Traverse to the DOC_ROOT folder

```
cd C:\xampp\htdocs
```

Play with the below command,

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

If DOC_ROOT has different public folder

```
php -S localhost:8080 -t public public/index.php
```

It worked fine for me.

Make sure the php.exe is added to the environment path.

Answer (score 0):

See if using scheduledtask works.

I had persisetnt difficulty calling a powershell script from PHP.  PHP kept timing out (not all powershell commands; only some commands.  Maybe it's got to do with security settings and how WAMP operates).  The following worked as a workaround.  Not elegant but it did the job.  In your case you only want to run a normal non-powershell commandline command, which is going ot be even simpler and the same method should work.

As for me, I called the powershell script as a **scheduledtask** as follwing (in PHP):

```
$cmd = 'c:\wamp64\www\runme4.bat';

$cmd2 = 'SCHTASKS /F /Create /TN _notepad3 /TR "'.$cmd.'" /SC DAILY /RU INTERACTIVE';

shell_exec($cmd2);

shell_exec('SCHTASKS /RUN /TN "_notepad3"');

shell_exec('SCHTASKS /DELETE /TN "_notepad3" /F');
```

The reason I had to put the powershell command in a .bat was because there were too many double quatation marks.  Single quotation marks would not work.   This is the content of my **runme4.bat** (note thre is a space between the two dots.  This poweshell command runs the ps1 script (the script is called AppointmentsToday.ps1) plus calls the function inside it.  The function inside it is called Get-AppointmentsToday):

powershell -executionpolicy Bypass -noexit ". .\Get-AppointmentsToday.ps1;Get-AppointmentsToday"

More specifically the **powershell script** in my case was something like this (To look for today's appointments in both the detault and user-defined calendars on the local version of Outlook 2019.  Fetch only subjects that contain hashtag or the word 'meeting'. Save the output result into a .txt file):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope CurrentUser -Force
Function Get-AppointmentsToday
{
 Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null
 $olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders" -as [type]
 $outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application
 $namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
 $folder = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderCalendar)
 $folder.items | Select-Object -Property Subject, Start

 foreach($customfolder in $folder.Folders)
    {
    $customfolder.items | Select-Object -Property Subject, Start
    }
} #end function Get-OutlookCalendar
 $todayStart = Get-Date -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0
 $todayEnd = Get-Date -Hour 23 -Minute 59 -Second 59
 Get-AppointmentsToday | where-object { $_.start -gt $todayStart -AND $_.start -lt $todayEnd -AND ($_.subject -ilike "*#*" -OR $_.subject -ilike "*meeting*") } | Out-File -FilePath \wamp64\www\AppointmentsToday.txt
```

The code ran smoothly when I entered Powershell myself, or called it myself from commandline.  However as soon as I tried to run it from PHP or as packaged in to an .EXE, the script failed to reach completion.  PHP kept timing out.  I removed all lines and then re-added them back in line by line.  From memory as soon as I uncommented these two lines, the execution stalled:
$folder = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderCalendar)
$folder.items | Select-Object -Property Subject, Start

The **scheduledtask** method worked for me.  Hope my approach helps someone in a similar situation.  You can also use this shedulestask method to run other .EXE applications if they fail to load using normal methods.  I'd be glad to learn of a better way to do things.