# Execute a .exe file with PHP using exec() on a distant server

Tags: php, exe

i made a game using php and JS, and i need to run some .exe files. i made all the test on local using MAMP and everything works fine. Now, i want to put the game on my website (i have the free version of planet hoster).

here is the code i wrote :
`$command = 'MartinS.exe'. ' '. $_GET['columns'] . ' ' . $_GET['rows'] . ' ' . $pixelArt; $output = exec($command);`

But when i try to play, the pages don't want to execute the .exe (it was working on localhost). i saw that someone has been able to run python script on planet hoster using exec(), but it simply don't work with .exe.
Do you have any ideas to solve that problem ?

Comment: You have to speak with the support of your hoster how to start a `.exe` file. This might be even not possible or supported at all. Hosters usually don't give access to their machines to execute any `.exe` file, that would be a huge security risk for them.

Comment: What kind of hosting plan did you buy? Usually shared hosting runs on Linux. .exe files usually only work on Windows (unless perhaps they are some cross-platform .NET executable, or something?)

Comment: P.S. `simply don't work` isn't a useful problem description. What do you get in `$output` when you run it? Is there any kind of error message? Does the hosting company give you terminal access? Can you run the .exe successfully direct from the terminal? I don't see much evidence of detailed investigations so far.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these two things first:

1. if your server is Windows, since .exe will only work on Windows environment
2. if you have enough permission on the server. It can be a case that your server is not allowing .exe to be executed (for various reasons, security and resource management included)

see more: [Run windows command in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830276/run-windows-command-in-php)